# School wifi blocks everything

Tags: software-installation

I've just returned to boarding school and the school network blocks everything. I cannot install anything with `sudo apt-get install`.

Does anyone know what can I do?

Comment: Ask your teacher about proxy they are using to use internet. (well don't forget to tell them, you are using it for educational purposes :) )

Comment: Actually it's probably the other way around, there *is* a proxy, and you have to enter the appropriate settings (in the `http_proxy` environment variable) for `apt-get` to work.

Comment: btw are you able to access internet using browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that they block **everything**?

If you have root access on the computer, and already installed eg. netcat or any similar tool (and of course some cleverness), you can try to find a way to proxy your traffic.

The most common case is to simulate DNS traffic (UDP port 53), as it is often left unblocked:

http://dnstunnel.de/